# How to add a NFT to metamask wallet with a RPC method

Tags: solidity, metamask, ethers.js, rpc

We have a way to add an ERC20 token to the metamask wallet from our dapps with a RPC method:

```js
    const addTokenToMetamask = async () => {
      if (typeof window.ethereum !== "undefined") {
        
        const tokenAddress = "0x;
        const tokenSymbol = "TOKEN";
        const tokenDecimals = 18;
        const tokenImage =
          "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/logo.png";
        
  
        try {
          // wasAdded is a boolean. Like any RPC method, an error may be thrown.
          const wasAdded = await window.ethereum.request({
            method: "wallet_watchAsset",
            params: {
              type: "ERC20", // Initially only supports ERC20, but eventually more!
              options: {
                address: tokenAddress, // The address that the token is at.
                symbol: tokenSymbol, // A ticker symbol or shorthand, up to 5 chars.
                decimals: tokenDecimals, // The number of decimals in the token
                image: tokenImage, // A string url of the token logo
              },
            },
          });
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      }
    };
```

As NFTs can be added from the v10.30 metamask version of the browser, I was wondering if there was any RPC method to add nfts to the metamask from our dapps.
If not, how would you do it?